# Find a harmonic function which goes to $0$ on the boundary, which is not identically $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

> Find a function which is harmonic on the area bounded by positive x
>   axis and the line $y=x$, which goes to $0$ on the boundary, which is
>   not identically $0$. Why doesn't it violate the max/min modulus principle?

I know that the function should be inside the "triangle", I was thinking about using the definition of harmonic functions, so my guess is that the function has to have a degree $\leq 2$.

Since the function has to be $0$ when $x=y$ or $x\in \mathbb R$ I tried to come up with examples like $x=y/2$ which decreases and goes to $0$ if we go up or down to the real line.

I'm not clear how to make it to go to $0$ on the boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do the same for the upper-half plane? ($u(x,y) = y = \operatorname{Im}(z)$ would be a good choice).

The function $z \mapsto z^4$ maps your "triangle" onto the upper-half plane, which suggests that
$$
u(x,y) = \operatorname{Im}(z^4) = 4xy(x^2-y^2)
$$
works. Verify that it does.

As for the question about the maximum principle, check the conditions in the theorem.

Comment: Thanks, I checked and the function indeed works, however, I don't understand the question about the upper-half plane. Why can $\operatorname{Im}(z^4)=\operatorname{Im}(z)=u(x,y)$? I see that if I take the argument of my triangle, multiply it by $4$, I get the upper plane.

Comment: I didn't say that $\operatorname{Im}(z^4) = \operatorname{Im}(z)$. Once you know conformal mappings, the above will make more sense.

Comment: how did you come with with this function? I tried to see if $xy(x-y)$ would work, but it didn't. I'm assuming you used conformal mappings which I haven't covered yet

Comment: @GRS Come up with an answer for the upper half plane "by magic". Then come up with a bijective holomorphic function mapping your triangle to the upper half plane. Your particular half plane is the range $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/4$; mapping $z$ to $z^4$ multiplies the argument by $4$, giving $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ which is indeed the upper half plane.

Comment: @Ian I read up about conformal maps, they preserve angles when $f'(z)\ne 0$, however, I didn't see how they would help in this problem. I don't see how the function $u(x,y)=y$ would work, when it's not defined on the line $y=x$ and how we go from $y$ to $4xy(x^2-y^2)$ is still unclear. I do see that we multiply the argument by $4$ to get the upperplane, and that's where the $4$ came from.

Comment: @GRS $u(x,y)=y$ is harmonic on the upper half plane and vanishes on the boundary of the upper half plane (which is to say the real axis). You then use the conformal mapping to turn your given domain into the upper half plane, and precompose $u(x,y)=y$ with that. When you do that you get the result above.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I'll try to figure it out

Comment: @GRS I misspoke slightly: I should say that you *postcompose* $u(x,y)=y$ with the conformal mapping (so that you are applying it after the transformation). That is the desired function is $u \circ f$ where $f$ is the conformal mapping.